# How to transmit a message to particular nodes in tinyOS?

Tags: receiver, transmission, tinyos, nesc

I am trying to implement a code in TINYOS TOSSIM, where node 1 transmits a message to node 2, then node 2 transmits to node 3, which transmits a message back to node 1. It seemed to be simple, everything goes well til the point where I have to transmit from 2 to 3 and my message is actually transmitted according to function AMsend.sendDone, however the receive event does not recognize any message transmitted to node 3. It looks like it just cannot find TOSSIM_NODE_ID == 3, however I specified it in my python and topology file, as well I can see that node 3 is booted and listening.

I posted the code, could you please suggest me where the error is or what I am doing wrong at this point. 
My C.nc file is as follows

```
#include <Timer.h>
#include "BlinkToRadio.h"

 module BlinkToRadioC {
   uses interface Boot;
   uses interface Leds;
   uses interface Timer<TMilli> as Timer0;
   uses interface Packet;
   uses interface AMPacket;
   uses interface AMSend;
   uses interface SplitControl as AMControl;
   uses interface Receive;
 }
 implementation
 {
   bool busy = FALSE;
   message_t pkt;
   uint16_t counter = 0;

   task void SendMsg1_2();
   task void SendMsg2_Radio();
   task void Intercept();


   //********************Boot Interface****************//
   event void Boot.booted()
   {
     dbg("Boot","Application booted for node (%d).\n",TOS_NODE_ID);
     call AMControl.start();
   }

   //********************SplitControl Interface*************//
   event void AMControl.startDone(error_t err)
   {
     if (err == SUCCESS)
     {
        dbg("Radio","Radio is on!\n");
        //if (TOS_NODE_ID == 1)
        //{
          //dbg ("Role","Node 1 starts sending periodical transmission.\n");
          call Timer0.startPeriodic(TIMER_PERIOD_MILLI);
     }
     else
      {
          call AMControl.start();
      }

    }

   event void AMControl.stopDone(error_t err)
    {      }


   //************************MilliTimer Interface********************//
   event void Timer0.fired()
   {
     post SendMsg1_2();
   }

   //***********************Task1 Interface*************************//
   task void SendMsg1_2()
   {
     counter++;
     //call Leds.set(counter);
   if (!busy)
     {
       if (TOS_NODE_ID == 1)
        {
        BlinkToRadioMsg* mesg = (BlinkToRadioMsg*)(call Packet.getPayload(&pkt, sizeof (BlinkToRadioMsg)));
        mesg->nodeid = TOS_NODE_ID;
        mesg->counter = counter;
        dbg ("RadioSend","Sending a message to node 2 \n");
          if (call AMSend.send(2, &pkt, sizeof(BlinkToRadioMsg)) == SUCCESS)
          {
            dbg_clear ("Pkg",">>>Pack \n \t Payload length %hhu \n", call Packet.payloadLength (&pkt));
            dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t Source: %hhu \n", call AMPacket.source (&pkt));
            dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t Destination: %hhu \n", call AMPacket.destination (&pkt));
            dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t AM Type: %hhu \n", call AMPacket.type (&pkt));
            dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t Payload \n");
            dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t node_id:  %hhu \n", mesg->nodeid);
            dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t msg_number: %hhu \n", mesg->counter);
            dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t value: %hhu \n", mesg->value);// call AMPacket.source (&pkt));
            dbg_clear ("Pkg","\n");// call AMPacket.source (&pkt));
          busy = TRUE;
          }
        }
     }
   }

   //***********************Task2 Interface*************************//
   task void SendMsg2_Radio()
   {
     counter++;
     //call Leds.set(counter);
   if (!busy)
     {
       if (TOS_NODE_ID == 2)
        {
        BlinkToRadioMsg* mesg = (BlinkToRadioMsg*)(call Packet.getPayload(&pkt, sizeof (BlinkToRadioMsg)));
        mesg->nodeid = TOS_NODE_ID;
        mesg->counter = counter;
        dbg ("RadioSend","Sending a message to node 3 \n");
          if (call AMSend.send(3, &pkt, sizeof(BlinkToRadioMsg)) == SUCCESS)
          {
          dbg_clear ("Pkg",">>>Pack \n \t Payload length %hhu \n", call Packet.payloadLength (&pkt));
          dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t Source: %hhu \n", call AMPacket.source (&pkt));
          dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t Destination: %hhu \n", call AMPacket.destination (&pkt));
          dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t AM Type: %hhu \n", call AMPacket.type (&pkt));
          dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t Payload \n");
          dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t node_id:  %hhu \n", mesg->nodeid);
          dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t msg_number: %hhu \n", mesg->counter);
          dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t value: %hhu \n", mesg->value);// call AMPacket.source (&pkt));
          dbg_clear ("Pkg","\n");// call AMPacket.source (&pkt));
          busy = TRUE;
          }
        }
     }
   }

   ///***********************Intercept Interface*************************//
   task void Intercept()
   {
  //   counter++;
     //call Leds.set(counter);
   if (!busy)
     {
        BlinkToRadioMsg* mesg = (BlinkToRadioMsg*)(call Packet.getPayload(&pkt, sizeof (BlinkToRadioMsg)));
        mesg->nodeid = TOS_NODE_ID;
        mesg->counter = counter;
        //dbg ("RadioSend","Sending a corrupted message to node 1 \n");
          if (call AMSend.send(1, &pkt, sizeof(BlinkToRadioMsg)) == SUCCESS)
          {
          busy = TRUE;
          }
     }
   }

  //***********************Receive Event Interface*************************//
   event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* msg, void* payload, uint8_t len)
   {
     if (len == sizeof(BlinkToRadioMsg))
     {
       if (TOS_NODE_ID == 2)
       {
         BlinkToRadioMsg* mesg = (BlinkToRadioMsg*)payload;
         call Leds.set(mesg->counter);
         post SendMsg2_Radio();
         dbg("RadioRec","Message successfully received at node 2 at time %s \n",sim_time_string());
         dbg_clear ("Pkg",">>>Pack \n \t Payload length %hhu \n", call Packet.payloadLength (&pkt));
         dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t Source: %hhu \n", call AMPacket.source (&pkt));
         dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t Destination: %hhu \n", call AMPacket.destination (&pkt));
         dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t AM Type: %hhu \n", call AMPacket.type (&pkt));
         dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t Payload \n");
         dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t node_id:  %hhu \n", mesg->nodeid);
         dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t msg_number: %hhu \n", mesg->counter);
         dbg_clear ("Pkg","\t\t value: %hhu \n", mesg->value);
         dbg_clear ("Pkg","\n");
       }
       else if (TOS_NODE_ID == 1)
       {
         BlinkToRadioMsg* mesg = (BlinkToRadioMsg*)payload;
         call Leds.set(mesg->counter);
         dbg("RadioRec","Message successfully received at node 1 at time %s \n",sim_time_string());
         post SendMsg1_2();
         dbg("RadioRec","Message received at node 1 at time %s \n",sim_time_string());
       }
       else if (TOS_NODE_ID == 3)
       {
         BlinkToRadioMsg* mesg = (BlinkToRadioMsg*)payload;
         call Leds.set(mesg->counter);
         dbg("RadioRec","Message is captured by adversary at time %s \n",sim_time_string());
         post Intercept();
       }
       else
       {
         dbg("RadioRec","Error encountered during reception! \n");
       }
     }
     else
     {
       dbg("RadioRec","Error encountered during reception! \n");
     }
     return msg;
   }

   ///***********************Senddone Event Interface*************************//
   event void AMSend.sendDone(message_t* msg, error_t error)
   {
      if (&pkt == msg&&error == SUCCESS)
      {
        if (TOS_NODE_ID == 1)
        {
          dbg("RadioSend","Transmitter ID is %hhu \n",TOS_NODE_ID);
          dbg("RadioSend","Packet has been successfully transmitted to node 2! \n");
          busy = FALSE;
        call Timer0.stop();
        }
        else if (TOS_NODE_ID == 2)
        {
          dbg("RadioSend","Transmitter ID IS %hhu \n",TOS_NODE_ID);
          dbg("RadioSend","Packet has been successfully transmitted to node 3! \n");
          busy = FALSE;
        }
        else if (TOS_NODE_ID == 3)
        {
          dbg("RadioSend","Transmitter ID IS %hhu \n",TOS_NODE_ID);
          dbg("RadioSend","Packet has been successfully transmitted to node 1! \n");
        }
        else
        {
          dbg("RadioSend","Error!Transmitter ID is not present! \n");
          dbg("RadioSend","Node ID is %hhu  \n",TOS_NODE_ID);
          post SendMsg2_Radio();
        }
      }
      else
      {
         dbg("RadioSend","Error encountered during the transmission! \n");
      }
   }
 }
```

and here is my python script

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from TOSSIM import *
import sys

out = sys.stdout

# Number of nodes in the simulated network is 3
number_of_nodes = 3

t = Tossim([])
m = t.mac()
r = t.radio()

#Open a topology file and parse the data, where first linebreak is transmitter nodeID, second is receiver nodeID and third is dBm value
f = open("topo.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    s = line.split()
    if s:
        print " ", s[0], " ", s[1], " ", s[2];
        r.add(int(s[0]), int(s[1]), float(s[2]))

# The type of debug messages that will be printed out. [add, comment and uncomment as you need]
t.addChannel("Init",out)
t.addChannel("Boot", out);
t.addChannel("Radio", out);
t.addChannel("Role",out);
t.addChannel("Led", out);
t.addChannel("RadioSend", out);
t.addChannel("RadioRec", out);
t.addChannel("Pkg", out);
#t.addChannel("Drop", sys.stdout);
#t.addChannel("Fwd", sys.stdout);
#t.addChannel("BASE", sys.stdout);
#t.addChannel("DBG", sys.stdout);
#t.addChannel("ERR", sys.stdout);
#t.addChannel("FILE", sys.stdout);

#Boot Nodes

time_boot = 0*t.ticksPerSecond();

print("Creating node 1...");
node1 = t.getNode(1);
#time1 = 0*t.ticksPerSecond();
node1.bootAtTime(time_boot);


print("Creating node 2...");
node2 = t.getNode(2);
#time1 = 0*t.ticksPerSecond();
node2.bootAtTime(time_boot + 10);

print("Creating node 3...");
node3 = t.getNode(3);
#time1 = 0*t.ticksPerSecond();
node3.bootAtTime(time_boot + 15);

#Add noise to the medium channel
noise = open("meyer-heavy.txt", "r")
for line in noise:
    str1 = line.strip()
    if str1:
        val = int(str1)
        for i in range(number_of_nodes):
            t.getNode(i).addNoiseTraceReading(val)

for i in range(1,3):
    print "Creating noise model for ",i;
    t.getNode(i).createNoiseModel()


# Simulation time is set to 9999
for i in range(9999):
    t.runNextEvent()
```

this is my output

[wsn@fadvisor Project_new]$ python project.py

```
  1   2   -60.0
  2   3   -60.0
  3   1   -60.0
  1   2   -60.0
Creating node 1...
Creating node 2...
Creating node 3...
Creating noise model for  1
Creating noise model for  2
0:0:0.000000000 DEBUG (1): Application booted for node (1).
0:0:0.000000001 DEBUG (2): Application booted for node (2).
0:0:0.000000001 DEBUG (3): Application booted for node (3).
0:0:0.000000010 DEBUG (1): Radio is on!
0:0:0.000000011 DEBUG (2): Radio is on!
0:0:0.000000011 DEBUG (3): Radio is on!
0:0:0.244140645 DEBUG (1): Sending a message to node 2 
>>>Pack 
     Payload length 6 
     Source: 1 
     Destination: 2 
     AM Type: 6 
         Payload 
         node_id:  1 
         msg_number: 1 
         value: 0 

0:0:0.247619628 DEBUG (2): Message successfully received at node 2 at time 0:0:0.247619628 
>>>Pack 
     Payload length 0 
     Source: 0 
     Destination: 0 
     AM Type: 0 
         Payload 
         node_id:  1 
         msg_number: 1 
         value: 0 

0:0:0.247619638 DEBUG (2): Sending a message to node 3 
>>>Pack 
     Payload length 6 
     Source: 2 
     Destination: 3 
     AM Type: 6 
         Payload 
         node_id:  2 
         msg_number: 2 
         value: 0 

0:0:0.247787474 DEBUG (1): Transmitter ID is 1 
0:0:0.247787474 DEBUG (1): Packet has been successfully transmitted to node 2! 
0:0:0.251525865 DEBUG (2): Transmitter ID IS 2 
0:0:0.251525865 DEBUG (2): Packet has been successfully transmitted to node 3!
```

Answer (score 2):

There maybe something going wrong on the TOSSIM side that makes the application stop (perhaps not polling enough events?). Maybe if you posted the Tossim script someone here might be able to spot the issue.

I changed the Tossim debug statements (dbg) to printf statements and ran the compiled TinyOS application using COOJA and got the output below. So node with ID 3 should be receiving the packet from node 2.

Also note that there is an small error in the Intercept task. You transmit to node 3 instead of transmitting to node 1.

[image]

Comment: Hi @KillaKem thanks for your answer, I edited my question and added my python script there. I have 10000 events which I think is more than enough to run such simple program.. I see that it runs for you in COOJA, that's weird. I don't have COOJA  though and I want to make sure it runs in terminal itself, could you suggest what is other possible reason for code to give a wrong output?